# What will happen if we return between pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop in Unix? And why?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, undefined-behavior

I read about this in [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment (3rd Edition)](https://www.amazon.ca/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-3rd/dp/0321637739),11.5,Thread Termination:

> If we run the same program on FreeBSD or Mac OS X, we see that the
>   program incurs a segmentation violation and drops core. This happens
>   because on these systems, pthread_cleanup_push is implemented as a
>   macro that stores some context on the stack. When thread 1 returns in
>   between the call to pthread_cleanup_push and the call to
>   pthread_cleanup_pop, the stack is overwritten and these platforms try
>   to use this (now corrupted) context when they invoke the cleanup
>   handlers. In the Single UNIX Specification, returning while in between
>   a matched pair of calls to pthread_cleanup_push and
>   pthread_cleanup_pop results in undefined behavior. The only portable
>   way to return in between these two functions is to call pthread_exit.

So,what I want to know is what is so called context on the stack, and what is overwritten and corrupted context like, and why return can't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a C function is called, it stores some information (like local variables) on the "stack" section of memory.  Likewise when this function calls another, this new function stores it's information just after the calling function's.

When the function call is over, it's memory is released/free'd, similar to taking a plate off a stack.  This space can now be reused.

[memory http://www.firmcodes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/memory.png](http://www.firmcodes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/memory.png)

If `pthread_cleanup_push` is implemented as a macro that stores information (context) on the stack, this memory will be free'd, and likely overwritten by the next function call.

If this happens before `pthread_cleanup_pop` is called,  there is a good chance that the "context" will have been overwritten by successive function calls thus corrupting the memory `pthread_cleanup_pop` was expecting to read from.

Comment: "this memory will be free'd, and likely overwritten by the next function call", that't true, but will this definitely result to the termination of the process because of segmentation violation? I think pthread_cleanup_pop will read the corrupted memory and its behavior will become unpredictable but not definitely  be terminated. what do you think?